# как сделать что бы блок выходил за пределы контейнера , а контент был в контейнере. пример https://prnt.sc/LVqJdc42gz36

Tags: html, css

пример как надо тут https://prnt.sc/LVqJdc42gz36

```css
.block{
  width: 800px;
}.arrow {
width: 100%;
}
.arrow-wrapper{
  position: relative;
  width: 47%;
  height: 56px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #EB6329;
  &::before{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    right: -29px;
    top: 0;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg width="29" height="57" viewBox="0 0 29 57" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path id="Vector 68" d="M0 57V0H12L29 28.5L12 57H0Z" fill="%23EB6329"/></svg>');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 29px;
    height: 56px;
  }
  &::after{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    right: -54px;
    top: 0;
     background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg width="29" height="57" viewBox="0 0 29 57" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path id="Vector 67" d="M12 0H0L17 28.5L0 57H12L29 28.5L12 0Z" fill="%23EB6329"/></svg>');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 29px;
    height: 56px;
  }
}

.arrow-title {
font-family: Gilroy;
color: #fff;
font-size: 18px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 700;
line-height: 100%; /* 30px */
letter-spacing: 0.9px;
text-transform: uppercase;
 }
.container{
  max-width: 760px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;

}

.dot{
  width: 100%;
}
.dot-container{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  
  
}
.set{
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 22px;
  color:#fff;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background: #464646;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="arrow">
    <div class="arrow-wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <span class="arrow-title">Этапы строительного цикла</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dot-container container">
    <p class="set">Work not haven money</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Пример

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.block {
  background-color: #555;
  padding-block: 2rem;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.arrow {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.arrow::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 0; right: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #EB6329;
}

.arrow-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 47%;
  height: 56px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #EB6329;
  &::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    right: -29px;
    top: 0;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg width="29" height="57" viewBox="0 0 29 57" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path id="Vector 68" d="M0 57V0H12L29 28.5L12 57H0Z" fill="%23EB6329"/></svg>');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 29px;
    height: 56px;
  }
  &::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    right: -54px;
    top: 0;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg width="29" height="57" viewBox="0 0 29 57" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path id="Vector 67" d="M12 0H0L17 28.5L0 57H12L29 28.5L12 0Z" fill="%23EB6329"/></svg>');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 29px;
    height: 56px;
  }
}

.arrow-title {
  font-family: Gilroy;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 100%;
  /* 30px */
  letter-spacing: 0.9px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.container {
  max-width: 760px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.dot {
  width: 100%;
}

.dot-container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
}

.set {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background: #464646;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">  
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="arrow">
      <span class="arrow-wrapper">
        <span class="arrow-title">Этапы строительного цикла</span>
      </span>
    </h2>
    <p class="set">Work not haven money</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: дружище огромное спасибоб я три дня сижу над этой штукой